# Create "namespace" in $(document).ready(function() {..});

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
// first.js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var MyNamespace = {};
});

// second.js
$(document).ready(function() {
   console.log(MyNamespace);
});
```

Running this script I'm getting error `Uncaught ReferenceError: MyNamespace is not defined`. I suppose, I'm getting this error because definition of `MyNamespace` and `MyNamespace` calling are in different scopes. How do I solve this problem?

I need to create namespace inside $(document).ready() wrapper because functions in this namespace will use jQuery methods etc.

What is the best practice?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you use two calls to `ready()`?

Comment: you need to define the variable outside the document ready function, then assign a value within the function. Or, take out the var

Comment: @Tomalak, one `$(document).ready()` I'm using in `first.js` and second in `second.js`

Comment: @Abe Petrillo, but I'm going to use `$` inside my namespace methods. So I have to be sure that jQuery is loaded and DOM is ready. It is the main reason why I'm asking this question...

Comment: @Kirzilla - You can still declare the namespace `var` outside of the `ready` event handlers. As long as code that requires the DOM to be ready stays inside, it won't make any difference.

Comment: As @JamesAllardice points out, resistance is futile :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you need to change:

1. Put the `MyNamespace` in a global scope;
2. **Avoid redefining** `MyNamespace` in each file;

You put `var MyNamespace = MyNamespace || {};` in front of both your js files. It decalres `MyNamespace` as an object if it isn't defined before.

```
// first.js
var MyNamespace = MyNamespace || {};
$(document).ready(function() {
   console.log(MyNamespace);
});

// second.js
var MyNamespace = MyNamespace || {};
$(document).ready(function() {
   console.log(MyNamespace);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It should work if you define your variable outside of the document ready handler -

```
var MyNamespace = {};
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log(MyNamespace);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the namespace outside the scope, then add methods to it within the scope:

```
var MyNamespace = {};

$(document).ready(function() {
   MyNamespace.MyFunction = function () { ... };
});
$(document).ready(function() {
   console.log(MyNamespace);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create it outside and update it inside:

```
var MyNamespace = {};

$(document).ready(function() {
   MyNamespace.Example = new function() { // do something };
});

$(document).ready(function() {
   console.log(MyNamespace);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `var` defines a variable local to the function, which is not visible outside of this scope. Leaving out `var` would define a global variable, accessible in the other function as well. In general you should rather avoid using global variables, but if that's what you need, simply say `MyNamespace = {};`

Answer (score -1):

Use the 'window' object.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window['x'] = 'test';
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert(x);
});
```