# JS namespace not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a bit odd to me as to why it isn't working in this sense. I have a namespace called
**PTN128.OPERATIONS**

It is created at the top level of the app in in a global file (some code omitted for space):

```
var PTN128 = PTN128 || {};
```

I then have a function called

```
PTN128.namespace = function ()
```

that creates my namespaces by way of

```
PTN128.namespace("PTN128.OPERATIONS");
```

[image: Default page screen shot]
In my default page I then define what PTN128.OPERATIONS (outside of jQuery stuff) is before I try to call it

```
PTN128.OPERATIONS = {}
```

It has a function in it called

```
fncInit: function ()
```

Using jQuery I then call this by way of

```
(function () {
  PTN128.OPERATIONS.fncInit();
}());
```

I always see in the console window the error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: OPERATIONS is not defined
```

When I do a

```
(function () {
console.log(PTN128.OPERATIONS );
PTN128.OPERATIONS.fncInit();
}());
```

I see the namespace OPERATIONS with the functions[image]. When I call the function directly from within the console window:

```
PTN128.OPERATIONS.fncInit();
```

I get the same error.

Everything for the namespace is defined outside of the

```
(function () {}());
```

I'm a bit lost right now of what to try next. I saw this post [Create “namespace” in $(document).ready(function() {..});](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224513/create-namespace-in-document-readyfunction) and looking at what I did looks to already be like this. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

---

Extra code for test purposes to see it

```
var PTN128 = PTN128 || {};
PTN128.namespace = function () {
var a = arguments, o = null, i, j, d;
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i = i + 1) {
    d = ("" + a[i]).split(".");
    o = PTN128;
    for (j = (d[0] == "PTN128") ? 1 : 0; j < d.length; j = j + 1) {
        o[d[j]] = o[d[j]] || {};
        o = o[d[j]];
    }
}
return o;
}
PTN128.namespace("PTN128.OPERATIONS");
PTN128.OPERATIONS = {
fncInit: function (console.log('test');
};
$(function () {
console.log(PTN128.OPERATIONS);
PTN128.OPERATIONS.fncInit();
}());
```

Comment: please also do a `console.log(PTN128.OPERATIONS.fncInit)`

Comment: Doing console.log(PTN128.OPERATIONS.fncInit) shows the function. Also, putting a console.log('test'); in the fncInit doesn't run.

Comment: Your `(function () {}());` is not using jQuery? Did you mean `$(function () {});`? Looks like you're executing this before assigning the `PTN128.OPERATIONS` object.

Comment: @Bergi but then how to explain than `console.log(PTN128.OPERATIONS );` returns expected object?

Comment: You're right, that *is* odd. Are you sure the errors are coming from the exact same place in the code?

Comment: A jQuery "ready" handler looks like this: `$(function() { ... })` - your examples are missing the `$`

Comment: @Pointy Anyway, i'm not sure how ready handler could be related to OP's issue here. OP should provide a jsFiddle which replicates his issue

Comment: You edited out a bunch of interesting context, and that makes it really hard to see what's going on.

Comment: The results are the same whether I have the $ or not. Doing $(function () {
    console.log(PTN128.OPERATIONS);
    PTN128.OPERATIONS.fncInit();
}()); gives same.

Comment: @ClumsyHamster Please provide minimalistic sample code where this issue can be seen

Comment: @Pointy what sort of extra code would you be looking for. Everything you are seeing other then how the namespace is created is there.

Comment: Once syntax errors fixed, it works here: http://jsfiddle.net/ayjtc/ but you don't need any IIFE here

Comment: @A.Wolff yes that looks fine. The call to that "namespace" function doesn't really matter anyway, since the "OPERATIONS" property is re-created in the next line of code.

Comment: Sorry typo on my part. The original code doesn't have the typo. Yeah, I see it working there. Not sure why it's not working here. I'll have to see about eliminating stuff until I get to the root. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Turns out it was much deeper. Sorry to have wasted everyone's time.